# TextInput label/id not getting picked up in detox

Tags: ios, xcode, detox

I am just setting up Detox and user error is possible... that being said, I think I'm doing this right. I have a TextInput element with both accessibilityLabel and testID set to email. However, detox cannot find UI element with by.id or by.label. The curious part is, I can find my identifier in xcode's view hierarchy. I'm not sure where to go from here? I've attached screenshots of the view hierarchy.

[image: xcode view hierarchy 1 of 2]

[image: xcode view hierarchy 2 of 2]

**Detox, Node, Device, Xcode and macOS Versions**

- Detox: 7.3.3
- Native: 0.54.2
- Node: 8.11.1
- Device: iPhone 7
- Xcode: 9.3
- macOS: 10.13.3

**Detox test**
As you can see, I'm attempting with both by.label and by.id. My test is:

```
describe('Boot and sign in', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        await device.reloadReactNative();
    });

    it('should have welcome screen', async () => {
        await expect(element(by.label('Login'))).toBeVisible();
    });

    it('should show login screen after tap', async () => {
        await element(by.label('Login')).tap();
        await expect(element(by.label('login-signin'))).toBeVisible();
    });

    it('should sign in and land on the homepage', async () => {
        await element(by.label('email')).typeText('qa@integrationtest.com');
        await element(by.label('password')).typeText('aaaaaa');
        await element(by.label('Sign in button')).tap();
        await expect(element(by.label('HOME'))).toBeVisible();
    });

    it('should sign in and land on the homepage', async () => {
        await element(by.id('email')).typeText('qa@integrationtest.com');
        await element(by.id('password')).typeText('aaaaaa');
        await element(by.id('Sign in button')).tap();
        await expect(element(by.id('HOME'))).toBeVisible();
    });
});
```

**Detox logs**

```
detox test
node_modules/.bin/jest e2e --config=e2e/config.json --runInBand --testNamePattern='^((?!:android:).)*$'
 server listening on localhost:64077...
 : Searching for device matching iPhone 7...
 : Uninstalling com.craftsy.membership...
 : com.craftsy.membership uninstalled
4: Installing /Users/steph.milovic/dev/craftsy-components/workspaces/membership/ios/Build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Membe ship.app...
4: /Users/steph.milovic/dev/craftsy-components/workspaces/membership/ios/Build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Membership.app i stalled
 : Terminating com.craftsy.membership...
 : com.craftsy.membership terminated
 : Launching com.craftsy.membership...
6: com.craftsy.membership launched. The stdout and stderr logs were recreated, you can watch them with:
        tail -F $HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C978D6DE-8373-4550-B3C9-25A8FB9FDB99/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_lo .{out,err}
 FAIL  e2e/app.test.js (18.811s)
  Boot and sign in
    ✓ should have welcome screen (1613ms)
    ✓ should show login screen after tap (2287ms)
    ✕ should sign in and land on the homepage (1333ms)

  ● Boot and sign in › should sign in and land on the homepage

    Error: Cannot find UI element.
    Exception with Action: {
      "Action Name" : "Type 'qa@integrationtest.com'",
      "Element Matcher" : "(((((kindOfClass('UILabel') || kindOfClass('UITextField') || kindOfClass('UITextView')) && hasText('Enter your email...')) || (kindOfClass('RCTTextView') && an object with accessibilityLabel "Enter your email...")) && !(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))) || (kindOfClass('UIScrollView') && ((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && ancestorThatMatches(((((kindOfClass('UILabel') || kindOfClass('UITextField') || kindOfClass('UITextView')) && hasText('Enter your email...')) || (kindOfClass('RCTTextView') && an object with accessibilityLabel "Enter your email...")) && kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))))))",
      "Recovery Suggestion" : "Check if the element exists in the UI hierarchy printed below. If it exists, adjust the matcher so that it accurately matches element."
    }

    Error Trace: [
      {
        "Description" : "Interaction cannot continue because the desired element was not found.",
        "Error Domain" : "com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain",
        "Error Code" : "0",
        "File Name" : "GREYElementInteraction.m",
        "Function Name" : "-[GREYElementInteraction matchedElementsWithTimeout:error:]",
        "Line" : "124"
      }
    ]

      at Client.execute (../node_modules/detox/src/client/Client.js:72:13)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        19.717s
Ran all test suites matching /e2e/i with tests matching "^((?!:android:).)*$".
child_process.js:644
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: node_modules/.bin/jest e2e --config=e2e/config.json --runInBand --testNamePattern='^((?!:android:).)*$'
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:601:13)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:641:13)
    at runJest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:110:6)
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:67:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/detox/local-cli/detox-test.js:54:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Comment: Did you get this figured out? Or is it still a problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also getting same issue randomly